# How can I get data from asp.net core webapi to angular 11.0.0 which is connected to database. I tried to do it but it returns empty records

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, angular, asp.net-core

This get the data from asp.net core webapi which is connected to Microsoft SQL Server. I'm trying to fetch but it returns undefined records in the list

```
    This is Get method:
    
    refreshList(){
        this.http.get(this.baseURL).toPromise()
            .then(res => this.list = res as PaymentDetail[]);
    }
    
    this is the way to make it accessible to html page:
    constructor(public service : PaymentDetailService) { }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
    
        this.service.refreshList();
    }
```

this the way I show in front End:

```
    <div class=col-md-6>
        <table class="table">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th>Card Owner</th>
              <th>Card Number</th>
              <th>Exp Date</th>
              <th></th>
    
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let pd of service.list">
              <td>{{pd.CardHolder}}</td>
              <td>{{pd.CardNumber}}</td>
              <td>{{pd.ExpirationdDate}}</td>
    
              <td>
                <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger"></i>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, when the AJAX request is made, what is the actual response from the server?

Comment: The request got 200 response so it fetch the data properly but it doesn't show up in the front end

Comment: Hi can you share the response data to the question? And completed code for `PaymentDetail`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response data is camel case format, so you need change the code below:

```
<tr *ngFor="let pd of service.list">
  <td>{{pd.cardHolder}}</td>
  <td>{{pd.cardNumber}}</td>
  <td>{{pd.expirationdDate}}</td>

  <td>
    <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger"></i>
  </td>
</tr>
```